# ipynb to py, move all file with name* to folder

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Hello I am trying to convert a notebook py to a regular python file, it creates new folders, and copies files to these based on the file name. How do I do this in py? Thanks!

```
 import os
 def setPath_getData():
    # Set up folders for data
    newpath = r'userdata' 
    if not os.path.exists(newpath):
        os.makedirs(newpath)
        os.makedirs(r'userdata/sleep')
        os.makedirs(r'userdata/distance')
        os.makedirs(r'userdata/steps')
        os.makedirs(r'userdata/lightly')
        os.makedirs(r'userdata/mod')
        os.makedirs(r'userdata/sedentary')
        os.makedirs(r'userdata/very')
        os.makedirs(r'userdata/heart-rate-zone')
        os.makedirs(r'userdata/heart-rate')
        
        # Get data from fitbit
        filenames = os.listdir("user-site-export")
        unique_filenames = set()
        for f in filenames:
            unique_filenames.add(f.split("-")[0])

        # Move files to seperate folders
        !cp user-site-export/sleep* userdata/sleep
        !cp user-site-export/distance* userdata/distance
        !cp user-site-export/steps* userdata/steps
        !cp user-site-export/lightly_active_minutes* userdata/lightly/
        !cp user-site-export/moderately_active_minutes* userdata/mod/
        !cp user-site-export/sedentary_minutes* userdata/sedentary/
        !cp user-site-export/very_active_minutes* userdata/very/
        !cp user-site-export/time_in_heart_rate_zones* userdata/heart-rate-zone/
        !cp user-site-export/heart_rate* userdata/heart-rate/

        !ls userdata/
        print("Data loaded successfully")
```

I tried now with

```
            # Get data from fitbit
        filenames = os.listdir("user-site-export")
        unique_filenames = set()
        for f in filenames:
            unique_filenames.add(f.split("-")[0])
        
        source = os.listdir('user-site-export/')
        dest = '/userdata/sleep/'
        
        for file in source:
            if file.startswith('sleep'):
                shutil.copy(file, dest)
            
            #ls userdata/
    print("Data loaded successfully")

setPath_getData()
```

but I am still not getting the files copied

Answer (score 0):

You can use shutil library to copy files. Snippet below can be used to copy source file to destination path. Yet, be careful destination path should be full (relative or absolute) path.

```
import shutil
shutil.copyfile(source, dest)
```

If you want to copy all directory then you should use the following

```
shutil.copytree(src, dest)
```

or more spesifically in your case

```
shutil.copytree("user-site-export/sleep","userdata/sleep")
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering, the problem is that in "user-site-export" I have a lot of different files, I only want the files named sleep1, sleep2 etc so all files which are named something with sleep

Comment: Then you can use a for loop within the directory and get only sleep files and copy with shutil.copyfile function

Comment: Hi, I edited my post to show what I tried, but it is not working, it get FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sleep-2020-01-09.json'

Comment: Shutil takes full path for both source and destination. Therefore you should also include filename on both source and destination.You should try shutil.copy("user-site-export/"+file, dest+file) in copy line.

Comment: it returns TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Comment: whats the type of file? It should have been string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219705/discussion-between-alperen-kantarci-and-mytivoli).

Comment: I got it 
for file in source:
            if file.startswith('sleep'):
                shutil.copy(os.path.join("user-site-export", file), 'userdata/sleep/')